# Uncaught exception that causes Abort

Tags: c++, exception

I'm using my own `Exception` class that inherits from `std::exception`. I'm pretty sure the class is okay since it has always worked up until now. I'm trying to throw an error from a constructor:

```
DataBase::DataBase()
  : _result(NULL)
{
  mysql_init(&_mysql);
  mysql_options(&_mysql,MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP,"option");
  if(!mysql_real_connect(&_mysql,"localhost","root","","keylogger",0,NULL,0))
    throw Exception(__LINE__ - 1, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, "Can't connect to DB");
}
```

Here is my try/catch block :

```
int main(int, char **)
{
  //[...]

  Server server([...]); // DB is a private member in Server

  try
  {
    server.fdMonitor();
  }
  catch (Exception &e)
  {
    std::cout << "Error: in " << e.file() << ", " << "function " << e.function()
          << "(line " << e.line() << ") : " << std::endl
          << "\t" << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return (1);
}
```

The problem is that the Exception thrown from my DB constructor isn't caught. Here's the abort message:

```
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Exception'
     what(): Can't connect to DB
 Aborted
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like the `DataBase` constructor is called from the `Server` constructor.

So, you need to move that line into the `try` block :

```
try
{
    Server server([...]); // DB is a private member in Server
    server.fdMonitor();
}
catch (Exception &e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the place which throws (construction of `server`) is not within the `try` block.